# Any way to Morph an object in Flex 4?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4.5, transition

I'm wondering if anyone has experience morphing an object from one skin/image/etc to another?

What I want to do is have an icon morph into another image went it goes into a dragging state. Much like how icons morph into their widgets when you add widgets to the mac dashboard.

Any way to get this to work would be helpful, including using the Flex 4.5 sdk or an external library for Actionscript.

Comment: I think your best bet would be PixelBender, but I don't know of any existing morphing shaders.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a mac no more so I'm not sure the exact effect. How about a ghetto edition of the effect. Have a skin class that has two layers, top layer is 100% opacity and bottom layer is 0%. The component it is associated to or a mediator would then listen to drag start event which it would then access the skin and apply a tween. The top layer's opacity will go from 100% to 0% over t seconds and the bottom layer's opacity will go from 0% to 100%.

Comment: in a way, that's what I've got going so far. the UX designer is pushing for a bit more of an effect though. Thanks for the suggestion!